# How to make for loop log line by line with 1sec delay in JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

My code will log all 10 lines in the order that I want (descending triangle), but I need it to delay 1 second before logging each successive line. I tried putting a setTimeout before the for loop, but that just caused a 1 second delay before printing all 10 lines concurrently.

```
function minusTen(num) {
  var arr = '';
  for (var i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    arr += '*';
  }

  var newArr = arr.split('');

  for (var j = num; j > 0; j--) {
    newArr.pop();
    console.log(newArr.join(' '));
  }
}

minusTen(10);
```

I can use jQuery but I'd like to avoid having to implement Bootstrap if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `setTimeout` for it but then you will have to keep `setTimeout` inside the for loop. you can also use `setInterval` here and clear the interval if num becomes 0. something like this:

```js
function minusTen(num) {
  var arr = '';
  for (var i = num; i > 0; i--) {
arr += '*';
  }

  var newArr = arr.split('');
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
     newArr.pop();
     console.log(newArr.join(' '));
     num--;
     if(!num)
        clearInterval(interval);
  }, 1000)
}

minusTen(10);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Someone recommended to me that I use a setInterval but I don't have a ton of familiarity with them, so I appreciate the demo!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function. Check the `.length` of `newArr`, if greater than `0`, call function again

```js
function minusTen(num) {
  var arr = '';
  for (var i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    arr += '*';
  }

  var newArr = arr.split('');

  function fn() {
    if (newArr.length)
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(newArr.join(" "));
        newArr.pop();
        fn()
      }, 1000)
    else 
      console.log("done, newArr.length:", newArr.length);
  }

  fn()
}

minusTen(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function minusTen(num) {
  var arr = '';
  for (var i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    arr += '*';
  }

  var newArr = arr.split('');

  function printLine(counter){
    var k = counter;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(newArr.join(' '));
        newArr.pop();
    }, k*1000);
    console.log(k);

  }

  for (var j = num; j > 0; j--) {
    printLine(j);
  }

}

minusTen(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to reduce your code footprint a little you could do something like this:

```
const printStars = (n) => {

  // Make sure we don't try to print zero stars
  if (n > 0) {

    // Fill an array with n stars
    const arr = Array(n).fill('*').join(' ');
    console.log(arr);

    // After a second, reduce n by 1 and call
    // the function again
    setTimeout(() => printStars(--n), 1000);
  }
}

printStars(10);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tp1ck3vy/1/)

It's worth pointing out here, however, that IE/Opera don't support [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

If you need to support them use an `for/loop` like in your example. Here I've separated out that code into its own function.

```
const getStars = (n) => {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr.push('*');
  }
  return arr.join(' ');
}

const printStars = (n) => {
  if (n > 0) {
    console.log(getStars(n));
    setTimeout(() => printStars(--n), 1000);
  }
}
```

[DEMO 2](https://jsfiddle.net/kaz5ybm6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout with an offset. Just add whatever parameters you need to the log function.

```
function log(offSet) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const str = new Array(offSet + 1).join('*');
    console.log(str);
  }, 1000 * offSet);
}

for(let i = 1; i < 11; i ++) {
  log(i);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ycreaL9w/

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward with async/await. `delay` holds the execution of the code for a specified amount of time.

```js
async function minusTen(num) {
  var arr = '';
  for (var i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    arr += '*';
  }

  var newArr = arr.split('');

  for (var j = num; j > 0; j--) {
    newArr.pop();
    await delay(1000)
    console.log(newArr.join(' '));
  }
}

function delay(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time))
}

minusTen(10);
```